# How to get a previous revision of an assembly from an open source project

Tags: version-control, open-source, assemblies, reference

I want to make use of Castle.Facilities.Logging.dll, however getting the latest version from the trunk causes problems with my already referenced version of Castle.MicroKernal.

Specifically, the error message is: "Assembly 'Castle.Facilities.Logging, Version=1.0.3.0, ...' uses 'Castle.MicroKernel, Version=2.0.0.0, ...' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Castle.MicroKernel, Version=1.0.3.0, ...'

Any idea how I can get hold of the Castle.Facilities.Logging.dll that references the particular versions of the other Castle assemblies that I have? Is this straightforward?

You might wonder why I don't just upgrade my other assemblies, but it's because I'm making use of a third party open source Architecture (SharpArchitecture), and when I have tried updating the assemblies previously I have run into all sorts of 'dependency hell'.

Edit:
I have tried getting the tagged 1.0.x-RC3 from the SVN repository, but find the build actually fails for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your assemblies from the [Castle build server](http://www.castleproject.org:8090/overview.html?guest=1). The "Windsor 2.x - .NET 3.5 - Release" build has the whole Castle stack built using the released Windsor.